# PyScripter Help docs missing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscripter

I am using the PyScripter IDE to edit my Python code. I was perusing the PEP 8 documentation and thought it would be worthwhile conforming to those specs. I tried changing the settings in PyScripter so it would format my scripts in this way automatically. So I went to Help > Python Manuals and nothing happened (I'm still waiting for something to happen). I then went to Help > PyScripter > Contents and up popped the PyScripter Help documentation, but as I clicked through all the chapters, there was no information at all - just blank output.

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Hey - do you have the latest pyscripter? I am on windows 7 and dont have that problem with v 2.5.3. Try  re-installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Works fine with 2.5.3 - try re-installing.

Comment: Good idea. Works fine now. Not sure what happened. Pretty simple solution. Should have thought of it myself. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Great! My favourite two commands - Ctrl-Alt-Del and reinstall :-)